# NULL out value in table 1, depending on a time-log in table 2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, table

I have two tables in MS SQL Server 2012. The first is a minute by minute production record which looks like (can't guarantee every single minute gets its own record, but never two records for one minute):

```
[myDateTime] [Produced]
12:01           100
12:02           110
12:03           115
12:04           100
```

The second table is a journal-style log of whether to consider the [Produced] column from Table 1 or not.

```
[myStartDateTime] [myEndDateTime]
     12:02            12:03
     12:47            12:58
```

I want to be able to look through each row of Table 1 and either take the [Produced] column, or take a NULL value, depending on if that minute falls within a record of Table 2 (ie between myStartDateTime and myEndDateTime INCLUSIVE).

In the example above, that would look like:

```
[myDateTime] [Produced]
12:01           100
12:02           NULL
12:03           NULL
12:04           100
```

I can't seem to get this to work (in code, or in my head). In my head I think I should join on myStartDateTime and join on myEndDateTime and make a new column called [Include] and set it to 1 or 0 depending on whether I want to include it or not. Each table might have 300 - 400 thousand rows and everything I am trying is slow.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This will get you the result you want, but it's a strange requirement.

If you want to make it fast, we'd need a lot more information, like table and index definitions, query plans, etc. "It's slow" isn't particularly helpful.

```
CREATE TABLE #crap1 (myDateTime TIME, Produced INT)

CREATE TABLE #crap2 (myStartDateTime TIME, myEndDateTime TIME )

INSERT #crap1 ( myDateTime, Produced )
SELECT *
FROM (
        VALUES('12:01', 100),
              ('12:02', 110),
              ('12:03', 115),
              ('12:04', 100)
     ) x (myDateTime, Produced)


INSERT #crap2 ( myStartDateTime, myEndDateTime )
SELECT *
FROM (
        VALUES('12:02', '12:03'),
              ('12:47', '12:58')
     ) x ( myStartDateTime, myEndDateTime )

SELECT c.myDateTime, CASE WHEN c2.myStartDateTime IS NULL THEN c.Produced
                          ELSE NULL
                     END AS Whatever
    FROM #crap1 AS c
    LEFT JOIN #crap2 AS c2
    ON  c.myDateTime >= c2.myStartDateTime
        AND c.myDateTime <= c2.myEndDateTime;
```